# Browser automation using Python 3.2

Tags: python, browser, selenium, automation

Do someone have an idea or know a library for browser automation COMPATIBLE with python 3.2 ? Because selenium which appear to be the best and many others are only for 2.7.

Thank you

Comment: Selenium is compatible with Python 3. `pip install selenium`.

Comment: Yap ! i found it, I had some misinformation ! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

[As mentioned by @Blender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18350842/browser-automation-using-python-3-2/41147837#comment26939349_18350842), you can install selenium for Python 3 with the command `pip install selenium`. Do note that you need Python 3.3+ (as of time of post) if you want to use the latest version of Selenium (3.0.2). ([source](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium))

Here's a [link](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/api.html) to Selenium 3's documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try [helium](https://pypi.org/project/helium/), which is based on [Selenium](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/), and very easy to use.

Install package:

> pip install helium

Import it your code:

> from helium import *

Start Chrome Browser:

> start_chrome('google.com')

For more details please visit, cheatsheet by the Author: https://github.com/mherrmann/selenium-python-helium/blob/master/docs/cheatsheet.md

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30260423)